# Logout from twitter api android

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to integrate my app to twitter and I do it

but my question is: How I can logout from twitter? can I remove RequestToken or OAuth of my app?

I tried to use:

- `twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(null);`

but does not work

- callbackUrl = "api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?force_login=true";

also does not work

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

@Rob answer is working, but this methods was removed in Twitter SDK v3.0.0

According to [upgrading guide](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/upgrading):

> [Removed] `TwitterCore#logOut()` was removed use
>   `TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().clearActiveSession()`
>   instead.

Answer (score 3):

In android application, if you are using Fabric and you want to logout from Twitter, try this:

```
Twitter.getInstance();
Twitter.logOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Current method

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove All Cookies

```
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

Remove  Specific Cookies

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("twitter.com", "auth_token=''");
```